# HTML/CSS/JavaScript how to add hyperlink to content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, code-injection, squarespace

I am currently making a [squarespace website for an art gallery](http://www.surfacegallery.org) and I have a [page that displays the current exhibitions](http://www.surfacegallery.org/current/). I added a code injection to change the message that is displayed when there is no exhibition currently on display:

```
<style> 
   .eventlist-empty:before { 
        content: "We are currently between exhibitions, please see the future page to see what's coming up soon.";
   } 
</style>
```

However I would like to add a hyperlink around "future page" that links to /future. Could someone tell me how best to do this please?

Thanks!

Comment: In CSS you can only style things. For displaying content you need HTML.

Comment: That can be accomplished with Javascript/jQuery

Comment: How would I do it using javascript? I don't think I can use html because the text is already produced by squarespace and I can't access it directly so I want to edit the text that is already there to say something else?

Comment: Introducing that question now extends this beyond what SO can do for you. It's far too broad for this platform.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the CSS property `content` in this way.

Your best solution is to use CSS to show/hide a link if necessary;

```
<style> 
   .eventlist .empty-link {
       display: none;
   }
   .eventlist-empty .empty-link { 
       display: block;
   } 
</style>

<div class="eventlist eventlist-empty">
    <a href="/future" class="empty-link">We are currently between exhibitions, please see the future page to see what's coming up soon.</a>
</div>
```

Comment: nice solution :)

Comment: Thanks @lupz for the edit - missed the class off the a tag.

Comment: This doesn't work because I want to change the existing text not add more text

Comment: `:before` won't replace the content of `eventlist-empty` though @Ben. Hide your existing text if the `.eventlist-empty` class is present. _Showing us your HTML will be a great help_

Comment: There is no html thats the problem lol, I have to use squarespace, the code in the question is the only code I have written as an injection

Answer (score 0):

I not sure that's possible. You can use JavaScript so when you click in the **p class=eventlist-empty**  redirect you to the feature page.

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('eventlist-empty')[0]; 
el.addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
   window.location.replace("stackoverflow.com"); 
}, false);
```

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: @Ben  var el = document.getElementsByClassName('eventlist-empty')[0];
el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}, false);

Comment: You need to change stackoverflow.com with your destination URL

Comment: It does, open the browser console and paste the code then click on the text, you'll see =)

Comment: I've added that code in script tags and changed the links but still nothing happens when you click http://www.surfacegallery.org/current/

Comment: It says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Comment: @Ben try with   var el = document.getElementsByClassName('eventlist-empty')[0];

if (el) {
  addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
  });
};

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('eventlist-empty') returns an empty list for some reason so it just does nothing

Answer (score 0):

I believe previous answers are missing one or more of the following considerations:

1. As you said, you do not have access to the underlying HTML (such is Squarespace when not using developer mode).
2. You must hide the existing text (which is added via Squarespace's default CSS for that template) either by setting `content: ""` or `display:none` or both.
3. You must remove the code you've added via code injection.
4. You must use **footer** code injection, not header.

Therefore, use the following code (via footer code injection) in place of what you had:

```
<style>
    .eventlist-empty:before {
        content: "";
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
    (function() {
        var emptyList = document.getElementsByClassName("eventlist-empty")[0];
        if (emptyList) {
            emptyList.innerHTML = "We are currently between exhibitions, please see the <a href='/future/'>future page</a> to see what's coming up soon.";
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Site Footer Injection

```
<script>
var emptyList = document.querySelector('.eventlist-empty');

if (emptyList) {
  var anchorEl = document.createElement('a');
  anchorEl.href = "/future";
  emptyList.parentNode.insertBefore(anchorEl, emptyList);
  anchorEl.appendChild(emptyList);
}
</script>
```

It'll simply wrap an anchor tag around this element for you